# Numpy/Torch insert smallest value in case of collision

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, pytorch

I have an empty numpy array, a list of indices, and list of values associated with the indices. The issue is that there may be duplicates in the indices. In all these "collision" cases, I'd like the smallest value to be picked. Just wondering what is the best way to go about it.
Eg:

```
array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
indices = [0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 4]
values = [1.0, 3.0, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 8.0]
```

Result:

```
out = [1.0, 0, 2.5, 1.5, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Can you provide a multi-dim minimal example with expected input/output?

Comment: There is no "empty NumPy array" in your example.

Comment: @norok2 `array` is the "empty array" - it is init with zeros.

Comment: @Shai as far as the code is concerned `array` is a `list` and not a NumPy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always implement something manually like:

```py
import numpy as np


def index_reduce(arr, indices, out, reducer=min):
    touched = np.zeros_like(out, dtype=np.bool_)
    for i, x in enumerate(indices):
        if not touched[x]:
            out[x] = arr[i]
            touched[x] = True
        else:
            out[x] = reducer(out[x], arr[i])
    return out
```

which essentially loops through the `indices` and assign the values of `arr` to `out` if not already *touched* (keeping track of this with the `touched` array) and reducing the output with the specified `reducer`.

**NOTE**: The `reducer` function needs to be such that the final result can only depend on the current and previous value.

---

The usage of this would be:

```py
indices = [0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 4]
values = [1.0, 3.0, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 8.0]
array = np.zeros(7)


index_reduce(values, indices, array)
# array([1. , 0. , 2.5, 1.5, 8. , 0. , 0. ])
```

---

If performances are of concern, you can also accelerate the above code with Numba with a simple decoration provided that also the `values` and `indices` inputs are NumPy arrays:

```py
import numba as nb

index_reduce_nb = nb.njit(index_reduce)


indices = np.array([0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 4])
values = np.array([1.0, 3.0, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 8.0])
array = np.zeros(7)


index_reduce_nb(values, indices, array)
# array([1. , 0. , 2.5, 1.5, 8. , 0. , 0. ])
```

---

## Benchmarks

The above solutions can be compared to a Torch-based solution (reworked from [@Shai's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73017786/5218354)):

```py
import torch


def index_reduce_torch(arr, indices, out, reduce_="amin"):
    arr = torch.from_numpy(arr)
    indices = torch.from_numpy(indices)
    out = torch.from_numpy(out)
    return out.index_reduce_(dim=0, index=indices, source=arr, reduce=reduce_, include_self=False).numpy()
```

or, with additional skipping of Torch gradients:

```
index_reduce_torch_ng = torch.no_grad()(index_reduce_torch)
index_reduce_torch_ng.__name__ = "index_reduce_torch_ng"
```

and a Pandas-based solution (reworked from [@bpfrd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73018858/5218354)):

```py
import pandas as pd


def index_reduce_pd(arr, indices, out, reducer=min):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(indices, arr))
    df1 = df.groupby(0, as_index=False).agg(reducer)
    out[df1[0]] = df1[1]
    return out
```

using the following code:

```py
funcs = index_reduce, index_reduce_nb, index_reduce_pd, index_reduce_torch, index_reduce_torch_ng

timings = {}
for i in range(4, 18):
    n = 2 ** i
    print(f"n = {n}, i = {i}")
    extrema = 0, 2 * n
    indices = np.random.randint(*extrema, n)
    values = np.random.random(n)
    out = np.zeros(extrema[1] + 1)
    timings[n] = []
    base = funcs[0](values, indices, out)
    for func in funcs:
        res = func(values, indices, out)
        is_good = np.allclose(base, res)
        timed = %timeit -r 16 -n 16 -q -o func(values, indices, out)
        timing = timed.best * 1e6
        timings[n].append(timing if is_good else None)
        print(f"{func.__name__:>24}  {is_good}  {timing:10.3f} µs")
```

to produce with the additional lines:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.DataFrame(data=timings, index=[func.__name__ for func in funcs]).transpose()
df.plot(marker='o', xlabel='Input size / #', ylabel='Best timing / µs', figsize=(6, 4))
df.plot(marker='o', xlabel='Input size / #', ylabel='Best timing / µs', ylim=[0, 500], figsize=(6, 4))
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.patch.set_facecolor('white')
```

these plots:

[image: bm_full]

[image: bm_zoom]

(the second is a zoomed-in version of the first).

These indicate that the Numba accelerated solution could be the fastest, closely followed by the Torch-based solution while the Pandas approach could be the slowest, even slower than the explicit solution without acceleration.

Comment: you did a nice job.

Comment: Is it possible the slight overhead of PyTorch over numba is due to "gradient book-keeping" done by pytorch? what if you "decorate" PyTorch's code with `@torch.no_grad()`?

Comment: @Shai my tests indicate that `@torch.no_grad()` slightly degrades the speed performances (~1-3 µs, from a few percent to percent fraction of the elapsed time).

Comment: I'd assume the overhead comes from the code required to deal with multi-dimensional arrays, although I am unsure how this actually works.

Comment: @norok2 very odd. Thank you for checking this out!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`index_reduce_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/generated/torch.Tensor.index_reduce_.html), which was introduced in PyTorch 1.12.

```py
import torch

array = torch.zeros(7)
indices = torch.tensor([0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 4])
values = torch.tensor([1.0, 3.0, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 8.0])

out = array.index_reduce_(dim=0, index=indices, source=values, reduce='amin', include_self=False)
```

You'll get your desired output:

> ```
> tensor([1.0000, 0.0000, 2.5000, 1.5000, 8.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000])
> ```

Note that this method is in "beta" and its API may change in future PyTorch versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas groupby agg` as the following:

```
indices = [0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 4]
values = [1.0, 3.0, 3.5, 1.5, 2.5, 8.0]
array = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(indices, values), columns=['indices','values'])
df1 = df.groupby('indices', as_index=False).agg(values=('values', min))

for i,j in zip(df1['indices'].tolist(), df1['values'].tolist()):
    array[i] = j
```

output:

```
array
>[1.0, 0, 2.5, 1.5, 8.0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: You could write the last two lines without explicit looping: `array[df1['indices']] = df1['values']`

Comment: @norok2 yes, if I convert array to numpy array `a = np.array(array, dtype=float)
a[df1['indices']] = df1['values']`

Comment: Also, converting to unlabelled columns reduces significantly the runtime.